# Solving separable differential equation

Tags: sympy, ode

I want to solve by SymPy simple separable equation y'=e^(y-x), but SymPy can't solve it!

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
y = Function("y")
dsolve(Eq(Derivative(y(x), x), exp(y(x)-x)), y(x))
```

But it solves successfuly similar equation y'=e^(y+x).

Any ideas how I can fix this problem are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try to find out what classifications sympy applies in both cases, if there are differences in content or order. Note that the symbolic ODE solvers are still rather incomplete and can contain errors. Please also tell us the value of `sympy.__version__`.

Comment: This is a bug. Please report it to github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, modifying the script to read

```python
eq = Eq(Derivative(y(x), x), exp(y(x)-x))
print(classify_ode(eq,y(x)))
```

returns

```
('factorable', 'separable', '1st_power_series', 'lie_group', 'separable_Integral')
```

The method for `'factorable'` seems broken, as you observed. Explicitly using the second method,

```python
dsolve(eq, y(x), hint='separable')
```

quickly returns the solution.

[image: solution formula]

For the other equation, the list of methods is

```
('separable', '1st_power_series', 'lie_group', 'separable_Integral')
```

so that the problematic method is not used. Why the trivial sign difference makes such a difference in the classificator only the developers will know.

Comment: Thank you! It's interesting that online version of SymPy works properly on this kind of DEs...

Comment: Check the versions, the online version was for a long time rather outdated. Especially `dsolve` has been thoroughly reworked in-between, so presumably contains less errors, but likely there were introduced different ones, which are often also "more interesting".

Comment: Online version of SymPy is 1.5.1. As I understand this is very old version in comparison with current version (1.9?) used in Google Colab for example.